# Determine if the end of a string overlaps with beginning of a separate string

Tags: ruby

I want to find if the ending of a string overlaps with the beginning of separate string.  For example if I have these two strings:

```
string_1 = 'People say nothing is impossible, but I'
string_2 = 'but I do nothing every day.'
```

How do I find that the `"but I"` part at the end of `string_1` is the same as the beginning of `string_2`?

I could write a method to loop over the two strings, but I'm hoping for an answer that has a Ruby string method that I missed or a Ruby idiom.

Comment: Please share what you've tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: @mwp I updated my question.  I could roll my own method that loops over the strings but what I'm hoping for is a Ruby string method or idiom that I missed.  Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not necessarily clear. If `string_1` is `"ab"` and `string_2` is `"bc"`, then does that count as overlap to you? If yes, then you gave a bad example as your example may imply that the overlapping border can be only word boundaries. If no, then you have not explained why, nor have you illustrated that fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `MARKER` to some string that never appears in your `string_1` and `string_2`. There are ways to do that dynamically, but I assume you can come up with some fixed such string in your case. I assume:

```
MARKER = "@@@"
```

to be safe for you case. Change it depending on your use case. Then,

```
string_1 = 'People say nothing is impossible, but I'
string_2 = 'but I do nothing every day.'
(string_1 + MARKER + string_2).match?(/(.+)#{MARKER}\1/) # => true

string_1 = 'People say nothing is impossible, but I'
string_2 = 'but you do nothing every day.'
(string_1 + MARKER + string_2).match?(/(.+)#{MARKER}\1/) # => false
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that would be much better.

Comment: Thanks everyone who submitted solutions.  I like this solution because of it's simplicity once I figured out the Regex.  My Regex skills are weak at best.  Performance is fine for my needs but I wonder how it would preform on long strings?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works by comparing the end of string_1 to the start of string_2—using the greatest common length as a starting point—with at least one matching character. It returns the index (from the end of string_1 or the beginning of string_2) if any matching character(s) are found, which can be used to extract the matching portion.

```
class String
  def oindex(other)
    [length, other.length].min.downto(1).detect do |i|
      end_with?(other[0, i])
    end
  end
end

string_1 = 'People say nothing is impossible, but I'
string_2 = 'but I do nothing every day.'

if (idx = string_1.oindex(string_2))
  puts "Last #{idx} characters match: #{string_1[-idx..-1]}"
end
```

Here's an alternative that finds all the indexes of the first character of the other string in the string, and uses those indexes as starting points to check for matches:

```
class String
  def each_index(other)
    return enum_for(__callee__, other) unless block_given?

    i = -1
    yield i while i = index(other, i.succ)
  end

  def oindex(other)
    each_index(other.chr).detect do |i|
      other.start_with?(self[i..-1]) and break length - i
    end
  end
end
```

This should be more efficient than checking every index, especially on longer strings with shorter matches, but I haven't benchmarked it.

Comment: I like the enum but how do you feel about `i = 0` and `i = rindex(other, i.pred)` and then `break i - length` this would allow for `def overlap(other); self[oindex(other)..-1] rescue nil; end;` which looks cleaner than the negation in my opinion

Comment: either that or simply `break i` which make sense too

Comment: @engineersmnky Rewriting either solution to return the offset into self rather than the number of matching characters is left as a trivial exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: And you want to work left to right with String#index (not right to left with String#rindex) to check for longer matches first.

Comment: Since we are looking for a tail end overlap you want to start at the right. Using `index` you will iterate twice `29` and `34` (once for each `b` in the string) using `rindex` will immediately hit `34` (the right most `b`)

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, but consider the case where there is repetition in the overlapping strings. To check "foofoofoo" and "foofoofoo" for overlap, I don't want to start at the last "f".

Comment: Fair enough I was assuming first overlap was sufficient *Hear Hear* :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple loop and test at the end:

```
a=string_1.split(/\b/)
idx=0

while (idx<=a.length) do
   break if string_2.start_with?(a[idx..-1].join)
   idx+=1
end

p a[idx..-1].join if idx<a.length
```

Since this starts at `0`, the longest sub string overlap is found.

You can use the same logic in a [.detect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) block on the same array:

```
> a[(0..a.length).detect { |idx| string_2.start_with?(a[idx..-1].join) }..-1].join
=> "but I"
```

Or, as pointed out in comments, you can use the strings vs the array

```
string_1[(0..string_1.length).detect { |idx| string_2.start_with?(string_1[idx..-1]) }..-1]
```

Comment: For the second example why not just use the strings instead? e.g. `string_1[(0..string_1.length).detect { |idx| string_2.start_with?(string_1[idx..-1]) }..-1]`

Comment: O perhaps premature optimization thinking the array might be faster than the string version. You are right tho. I will add that.

Comment: Yeah generally `String` mechanisms are faster than conversion

Comment: *Yeah generally String mechanisms are faster than conversion*: but there are fewer actions under the array method vs the string method. One per word vs one per character.

Comment: I totally understand but in this case String benchmarks under the Array possibly due to the regex which is notoriously slow. Additionally words are semantic and the question does not state that "ut I..." should not also match

Comment: @engineersmnky: Agreed.

Comment: `"my oh my".split /\b/ #=> ["my", " ", "oh", " ", "my"]`. Is that intended?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: *Is that intended?* Yes, absolutely. Suppose you have `'Word\tword\t\tword       word word'` using this method you can reassemble the original string including nonstandard spacing between the words. `string.split(\b).join == string` even if there are tabs, spaces, multiple tabs and spaces in the string.

Comment: That's interesting. I've tucked it away.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do that. The first converts the two strings to arrays and then compares sequences from those arrays. The second operates on the two strings directly, comparing substrings.

**#1 Convert strings to arrays and compare sequences from those arrays**

Here's a simple alternative that requires the strings to be converted to arrays of words. It assumes all pairs of words are separated by one space.

```
def begins_with_ends?(end_str, begin_str)
  end_arr = end_str.split
  begin_arr = begin_str.split
  !!begin_arr.each_index.find { |i| begin_arr[0,i+1] == end_arr[-1-i..-1] }
end
```

`!!obj` converts `obj` to `false` when it's "falsy" (`nil` or `false`) and to `true` when it's "truthy" (not "falsy"). For example, `!!3 #=> true` and `!!nil #=> false`.

```
end_str   = 'People say nothing is impossible, but I when I'
begin_str = 'but I when I do nothing every day.'
begins_with_ends?(end_str, begin_str)
  #=> true
```

Here the match is on the second word `"I"` in `begin_str`. Often, however, the last word of `end_str` only matches (at most) a single word in `begin_str`

**#2 Compare substrings**

I've implemented the following algorithm.

1. Set `start_search` to `0`.
2. Attempt to match the last word of `end_str` (value of `target`) in `begin_str`, beginning at offset `start_search`. If no match is found return `false`; else let `idx` be the index of `start_str` where the last character of `target` appears.
3. Return `true` if the string comprised of the first `idx` characters of `begin_str` equals the string comprised by the last `idx` characters of `end_str`;  else set `start_search = idx + 2` and repeat step 2.

```
def begins_with_ends?(end_str, begin_str)
  target = end_str[/[[:alnum:]]+\z/]
  start_idx = 0
  loop do
    idx = begin_str.index(/\b#{target}\b/, start_idx)
    return false if idx.nil?
    idx += target.size
    return true if end_str[-idx..-1] == begin_str[0, idx]
    start_idx = idx + 2
  end
end
```

```
begins_with_ends?(end_str, begin_str)
  #=> true
```

This approach recognizes different numbers of spaces between the same two words in both strings (in which case there is no match).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would meet your needs?

```
string_1.split(' ') -  string_2.split(' ')
=> ["People", "say", "is", "impossible,"]
```

Or this is more convoluted, but would give you the exact overlap:

```
string_2.
  chars.
  each_with_index.
  map { |_, i| string_1.match(string_2[0..i]) }.
  select { |s| s }.
  max { |x| x.length }.
  to_s
=> "but I"
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither one of these really meets the requirements of determining if the end of `string_1` overlaps the beginning of `string_2`